# Summary Index In splunk

Tags: splunk, splunk-query, splunk-calculation

can you please help me with time stamp of summay index..
we having disk space issue and we are clearing the old logs . but we want keep some field data so if will schedule a SI then does it will add the data from last 1 month at one time ..then why we need to schedule it ? have gone through the splunk document but unable to understand the steps and logic  ..

Answer (score 1):

The idea of a summary index is to store the results of a search until they are needed for a later search.  The classic example is the end-of-month report. Rather than run a huge search over thirty days to crunch the thousands of events of each day into a final report, a daily search crunches the events of that day into a SI then the monthly report runs on day 30 to read the 30 summary events from the SI into a report that runs quickly.  The same SI can then be used for end-of-week reports and to populate a dashboard with the daily sales (or whatever) figures.

The key is to make the summary *smaller* than the original data.  One cannot dump 1 month of data into a SI and hope to save space - it won't happen.

A summary index can help save disk space by retaining a smaller set of summary data long after the original events have been discarded.

Summaries do not have to be scheduled, but that is the most common way to producing them.  It means no one has to remember to run the daily sales reports everyday to be able to get the monthly sales report.  That said, one can write events to a summary index in an ad-hoc search using the `collect` command.

Comment: thanks @RichG ..so i hv 1 index  with multiple fields now i want SI to store 2,3 fields value from jan to till date so that we can delete the file whose ageing is more then 10 days because of space crunch . how can i schedule that .. what would be the time range i need to select  because in first run it has to gather one month data then every day it will run for last 24 hour ..

Comment: Run the one month summary manually then schedule the daily updates.